# How to identify available environmental variables for applications?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

On Linux, the `crontab` editor can be configured to open with `nano` using the following command:

```
$ EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

This "EDITOR" env is mentioned in the crontab manual, but is there a way to identify which envs can be modified with other command line tools (without reading all the manuals...)?

For example, my imaginary `showenvs` command:

```
$ showenvs crontab
     EDITOR=""
     VISUAL=""
```

Answer (score 1):

No. There is nothing special about these variables, they're just variables. Whether they are used by a program is completely up to the developers of that program. So I could write a tool that expects the variable `ASLDKB` to be defined. That just means that my code will look for that variable in the user's environment, but there will be nothing else special about the variable itself.

In other words, what you are asking for is impossible. While you might be able to get a list for certain standard variables, a complete list of what variables currently defined in your environment might be used by any program is impossible to get.

Comment: In addition, if a program uses a dynamic library, the library itself could read some environment variable (e.g. libcurl and `https_proxy` variable). Note that, in this case, you'll find no trace of the variable in program source code and even the program developers will not know that that variable is meaningful to their program.